# Using arrays as elements of arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I have a problem with the method "update()" in the following code. I tried to to use arrays as elements of the array "hyp", since the individual arrays do not all have the same size.
Now in the update function I want to compare the elements that are stored in position 0 of the individual arrays, e.g. sky[0], in the j-th position of hyp with the corresponding elements in the trainingexample array.
The problem I have is that I can only access the address for each array in the j-th position of the hyp array. I tried to assign the array in the j-th position, i.e. hyp[j], to a variable of type Object[], but this did not work. Should I just use multidimensional arrays, even though there would be empty elements in it or is there a better solution than what I'm trying to do here?

```
public class FindS {
static Object[] sky = {"Sunny", "Cloudy", "?", "0", 0};
static Object[] airtemp = {"Warm", "Cold", "?", "0", 0};
static Object[] humidity = {"normal", "high", "?", "0", 0};
static Object[] wind = {"strong", "weak","?", "0",0};
static Object[] water = {"warm", "cold","?", "0", 0};
static Object[] forecast = {"same", "change","?", "0", 0};

static Object[] hyp = {sky,airtemp,humidity,wind, water, forecast};


public static String[] trainingexample = new String[7];


public static int findindex(Object[] a, String s){
    int index = 0;
    while (index != a.length - 1){
        if (a[index] == s)
            return index;
        index++;
    }
    return -1;

}

public static void exchange(Object[] a, String s){
    int exchindex = findindex(a, s);
    try{
        Object temp = a[exchindex];
        a[exchindex] = a[0];
        a[0] = temp;
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
    {
        System.out.println(s + "not found");
    }
}

public void update(){
    if (trainingexample[6] == "0");
    else{
        int j = 0;
        while ( j != hyp.length){
            Object[] temp = hyp[j];
            if (temp[0] == trainingexample[j]);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That code won't compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be best to define `hyp` as a multidimensional array.

```
static Object[][] hyp = {sky,airtemp,humidity,wind, water, forecast};
```

Then your assignment would work:

```
Object[] temp = hyp[j];
```

Alternatively, but less clearly, you could just cast `hyp[j]` as `Object[]`, but I wouldn't recommend it.

```
Object[] temp = (Object[]) hyp[j];
```

Answer (score 0):

The hyp at particular index j will return Object.

```
static Object[] hyp = {sky,airtemp,humidity,wind, water, forecast};
```

So change  `Object[] temp = hyp[j];` to  `Object temp = hyp[j];`

Comment: Yes I know, but I need to be able to refer to the first element in temp so to say, but temp only contains the address of that array, so I'm unable to call temp[0].